# Extract variable name in R from string in a vector

Tags: r, string, dplyr, count, evaluation

I want to use some strings inside a vector as variable names for some dplyr verbs, mostly count.

Let's work with Iris and assume I have this vector:

```
my_vec <- c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width","Species")
```

If I decide to `count(Species)` everything is fine.

```
> iris %>% count(Species)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species        n
  <fct>      <int>
1 setosa        50
2 versicolor    50
3 virginica     50
```

The problem is that when I want to use the string saved in the vector the program doesn't evaluate it properly.

```
> iris %>% count(my_vec[5])
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `my_vec[5]`     n
  <chr>       <int>
1 Species       150
```

How can I use the value of `my_vec[5]` to obtain the first table and not the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
     count(!! rlang::sym(my_vec[5]))
#     Species  n
#1     setosa 50
#2 versicolor 50
#3  virginica 50
```

If it is more than one elements, use `syms` and evaluate with `!!!`

Comment: Thank you! This is what I wanted. I tried for half an hour to use enquo, sym, bang bang, etc. but didn't realize I had to use them in conjunction.